# Writing jQuery plugin -- multiple instantiation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding the local variables for my jQuery plugin. I am pretty sure if I declare them outside the main jQuery function register, then every time the plugin is called it will redefine the variables.

Example:

```
(function($){
    jQuery.fn.test = function(options){
        if ( options ) { 
            $.extend( settings, options );
          }
        this.each(function(i,item){
            // do whatever i am going to do
        });

    };


    var settings = {
        value1: "hello",
        value2: "word"
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Say that `$(object).test({value1:'newterm'});` is called multiple times.. Am I correct in thinking that every time that method is called, that it will override the settings with the most recently declared settings?

If i want multiple instances of my plugin, do I need to declare everything within the scope of the main `jQuery.fn.test = function(){//here}` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, because `$.extend` will modify `settings` which is in the closure scope exposed when the jQuery initialization function sets up `.test` on the global object jQuery. That closure scope is the same everytime you execute `.test`; therefore, all objects will retain changes.

Comment: Figured, I moved all the associated functions and vars into the jQuery.fn = function and all is good, just wanted to verify, thanks

Comment: Ya, sometimes it's hard to keep scoping straight in your head in javascript ;) Btw, if you liked the answer, could you accept it? :)

Comment: Ofcourse! had to wait for the 5 min timer to finnish. Yeah I was unsure due to seeing many plugins keep their methods and data outside that initializing function so I figured the main (function()... wrapper was called for each initialization, obviously its only used once to register your plugin with jQuer lib though

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the order you pass objects to $.extend. The first (target) object passed will be modified, in your case the settings object. If you want to keep the defaults:

```
$.extend(options, settings);
```

Or to get a brand new object:

```
var newoptions = $.extend({}, options, settings);
```